# Syling Custom Fields echo's from from functions.php

Tags: functions, custom-field, id, genesis-theme-framework, css

With the help of [User Borek](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/45286/borek) I've managed to get Custom Fields displaying on my siteby putting the below in the functions.php:

```
function custom_field_before_content() {
if(is_page() || is_single() || is_archive() ) {
    echo genesis_get_custom_field('instrument');}
}
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'custom_field_before_content' );
```

I'm having trouble putting an id or class on them though so I can style them. I am using a Genesis theme and I can't figure out how to do this. I have tried following [this tutorial](http://wpsites.net/web-design/how-to-create-a-custom-field/) with no success. Does anyone know where I can put an id or class on these custom fields in a genesis theme?

This is one of the pages where my custom fields are displaying: http://bethlehem-music.org/?p=18. Right above the image and under the title.

Appreciate any help,

Ciarán

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just echoing out the needed syntax like that:

```
echo '<div class="custom-field">' . genesis_get_custom_field('instrument') . '</div>';
```

You can also just use CSS and style the

```
header.entry-header {
    //your sexy styles goes here
}
```

Since other elements inside are wrapped in their own elements and styled separately (I mean the actual H1 and meta data) the only altered item will be the bare custom field value.

Comment: Thanks again Borek I really owe you for this! Appreciate it.

Comment: @Ciarán No problem